# Connecting two mysql of different pc using lan

Tags: java, mysql

i have connected two pc using lan

ip address of 1st pc(server) 169.254.148.190
and ip address of 2nd 169.254.99.60

now i want to connect mysql between these pc

i use the following code

" Grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'%'; "

it gives an error 
error 1133: Can't find any matching row in the user table.

and when i am trying to connect through java

jdbc:mysql://169.254.99.60:3306/mysql","root","root"

it gives error

communication link failure
last packet sent sucessfull to server was 0 Milliseconds ago. The driver didn't receive any package from server.

please help me!! what should i do.

Comment: you should set up a proper network and not use the 'i dont know what my ip address is HALP!' default address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to reconfigure the MySQLInstance running `MySQL Server Instance Config Wizard` and making two changes in configuration

[image: first change]

[image: second change]

in first image tick on Add Firewall exception for this port and in second image tick on enable root access from remote machines..

it will solve your problem..